# Marked is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, javascript-marked

I'm trying to build a markdown previewer using react and the marked node package. Everything works up to when I try to parse any markdown on the DOM. When I do I get an error message: Uncaught TypeError: marked is not a function.

I have marked declared at the top of the file like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
const marked = require("marked");
```

I also tried declaring marked like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
const { marked } = require("marked");
```

But this didn't seem make a difference.

This is my code configuration:

```
            <div className="preview-label">Preview</div>
            <div
              id="preview"
              className="preview-area"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: marked(mrkdwn),
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
```

I've also tried:

```
            <div className="preview-label">Preview</div>
            <div
              id="preview"
              className="preview-area"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: marked.parse(mrkdwn),
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
```

```
            <div className="preview-label">Preview</div>
            <div
              id="preview"
              className="preview-area"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: marked.parser(mrkdwn),
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
```

and

```
            <div className="preview-label">Preview</div>
            <div
              id="preview"
              className="preview-area"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: marked.Parser(mrkdwn),
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
```

However, I've also gotten similar error messages with these attempts as well, only in these cases the messages say .Parser, .parse, .parser, etc., is not a function.

If you need to see anymore code, please let me know.

I haven't been able to find a solution in any of my Googling. It's possible there's something out there I missed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is `marked` declared? It appears to be undefined in your snippets. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found that I'm supposed to import marked like this:

```
import { marked } from 'marked'
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what was missing!

Answer (score 2):

this was what worked for me.

```
const { marked } = require('marked');
```